# Mask the name of a controller, Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a controller posts:
www.mydomain.com/posts/123-hello

Please bear in mind that the 123 is unique for each post but is not the correlative id (post.permalink)

I want to access the posts through addresses like:

www.mydomain.com/is/123-hello
*not

www.mydomain.com/posts/123-hello*

I have a `to_param` in my Post model to construct the "123-hello", but when I use `redirect_to @post` I end in www.mydomain.com/posts/123-hello

How can I do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
map.resources :posts, :as => "is"
```

For the permalink part, see this question (but it looks like you've already got it right):

[Rails routing - custom routes for Resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268801/rails-routing-custom-routes-for-resources/2268831)

Comment: Thank you, Tomas! Worked perfectly

Comment: as in rails 3.2x it is probably renamed to `path`. so for this version the above routing may be like `resources :posts, :path => 'is'`